# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am receiving an object from other component in NodeJs. When I am displaying content of variable it is perfectly printing. But when i am using any property it is giving error.

when I am printing orgList it is displaying perfectly.

```
 orglist  : {"count":5,"items":[{"organizationName":"FTE Process Org","organizationCode":"FP1"},{"organizationName":"FTE Discrete Org","organizationCode":"T11"},{"organizationName":"Product development Org","organizationCode":"PD2"},{"organizationName":"Product1 development Org","organizationCode":"PD1"},{"organizationName":"Main development Org","organizationCode":"MD1"}]}
```

But when I am printing `orgList.items` it is displaying `undefined`.
when I am printing `orgList.items.length` it is giving "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

How can i resolve this error?

Below is the screenshot of log.

[image]

Comment: Is `items` populated asynchronously?

Comment: Have you parsed the content before using?

Comment: Please share the code that produces the values.

Comment: It is json object. I dont know how to parse. will json.stringyfy work?

Comment: @Chase value is produced by chatbot.

Comment: No stringify is the opposite of parsing (JSON.parse)

Comment: `JSON.parse(orglist)` should do the trick

Comment: Please post code with both `console.log()` and where `orgList.items` is populated. Check the type of `orgList.items`. This is not a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is JSON you may want to try:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(orglist);
console.log(obj.items.length);

// and if you want to test it isn't undefined / null
if (obj.items) {
  console.log(obj.items.length);
}

// or
console.log(obj.items?.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

the first you should update `:` to `=` and using the same name for getting out put (orgList != orglist).  using this code:

```js
    var orgList = {
      "count": 5,
      "items": [
        {
          "organizationName": "FTE Process Org",
          "organizationCode": "FP1"
        },
        {
          "organizationName": "FTE Discrete Org",
          "organizationCode": "T11"
        },
        {
          "organizationName": "Product development Org",
          "organizationCode": "PD2"
        },
        {
          "organizationName": "Product1 development Org",
          "organizationCode": "PD1"
        },
        {
          "organizationName": "Main development Org",
          "organizationCode": "MD1"
        }
      ]
    }
    
    console.log(orgList.items.length);
```

update : to = and using the same name for getting out put.